# Not allowed to use async/await while using serverActions in Client component in next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, async-await

Building an infinite scroll in next.js, I am trying to call my serverAction to loadMoreData and using async/await with it to wait for the API call and get result.

Getting an error:

**"async/await is not yet supported in Client Components, only Server Components."**

page.tsx is a server component and calls the same server action one time for initial images.

```
// page.tsx

const Home = async ({ searchParams }) => {

  const searchKeyword =
    typeof searchParams.keyword === "string" ? searchParams.keyword : "";
  
  let apiResponse = await getPhotos({ query: searchKeyword });

  return (
    <main className='p-6 flex justify-center w-full min-h-screen bg-black'>
      <InfiniteScrollData
        search={searchKeyword}
        initialData={apiResponse?.results || []}
      />
    </main>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

Here is the server action:

```
// actions.ts

"use server";


export const getData = async ({
  query,
}) => {
  
  const { response } = await fetchData({
    query,
  });
  apiResponse = response;
  
  return response;
};
```

And following is the client component

```
// InfiniteScrollData.tsx

"use client";

// imports


const InfiniteScrollImages: = ({
  search,
  initialData,
}) => {
  const [data, setData] = useState(initialData);
  const [page, setPage] = useState(1);
  const [loaderRef, inView] = useInView();

  const loadMoreData = useCallback(async () => {
    const next = page + 1;
    const response = await getData({ query: search, page: next });
    if (response?.results?.length) {
      setPage(next);
      setData((prev) => [...prev, ...(response?.results || [])]);
    }
  }, [page, search]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (inView) {
      loadMoreData();
    }
  }, [inView, loadMoreData]);

  return (
    <>
      <div>
        {photos?.map((item) => (
          <Card key={item.id} data={item} />
        ))}
      </div>
      <div ref={loaderRef}>
        <Loader />
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default InfiniteScrollImages;
```

Using next@14.0.1

Maybe there is another way of calling server actions from client components?

Comment: do you perhaps need to add `"use server";` to the `page.tsx` as well to make it explicitly a server component?

Answer (score 1):

> Maybe there is another way of calling server actions from client components?

You have two options:

1. Turn `getData` to client code - This just requires that getData is moved from the actions file without the `"use server"` directive and your code should work  as expected. But I'm sure you wouldn't want this.
2. The second is to follow react's docs and call the Server Action in a transition. You would need to modify your `loadMoreData` handler as below:

```js
const loadMoreData = useCallback(() => {
    startTransition(async () => {
      const next = page + 1;
      const response = await getData({ query: search, page: next });
      if (response?.results?.length) {
        setPage(next);
        setData((prev) => [...prev, ...(response?.results || [])]);
       }
    });
}, [page, search]);
```

More information is available on [react's docs on server actions](https://react.dev/reference/react/use-server#calling-a-server-action-outside-of-form)

Answer (score 1):

there are 2 options to call server actions in client components.

First is [using bind](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/server-actions)

> You can bind arguments to a Server Action using the bind method. This
> allows you to create a new Server Action with some arguments already
> bound. This is beneficial when you want to pass extra arguments to a
> Server Action.
>
> Good to know: .bind of a Server Action works in both Server and Client
> Components. It also supports Progressive Enhancement.
>
> Progressive enhancement allows a  to function properly without
> JavaScript, or with JavaScript disabled.

since you are [Calling a Server Action outside of form, u need to use useTransition](https://react.dev/reference/react/use-server)

> When using a Server Action outside of a form, call the Server Action
> in a transition, which allows you to display a loading indicator, show
> optimistic state updates, and handle unexpected errors. Forms will
> automatically wrap Server Actions in transitions.

since we usually navigate the user to somewhere else, `startTransition` makes sure we redirect after data is changed.

Answer (score 0):

As the error suggested async await isn't supported in client components.
Your alternative would be to handle promises. Your getData async function returns a promise which you can handle in your useCallback or just return the promise there as well and handle the promise in the useEffect

Without a demo I am kind of guessing so here is a rough solution:

```
const loadMoreData = useCallback(() => {
    const next = page + 1;
    getData({ query: search, page: next }).then(response => {
      if (response?.results?.length) {
        setPage(next);
        setData((prev) => [...prev, ...(response?.results || [])]);
      }
    }).error(() => {

    });
  }, [page, search]);
```

On Nextjs documentation for client data fetching this is the example they give:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'

  function Profile() {
    const [data, setData] = useState(null)
    const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(true)

    useEffect(() => {
      fetch('/api/profile-data')
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((data) => {
          setData(data)
          setLoading(false)
        })
    }, [])

    if (isLoading) return <p>Loading...</p>
    if (!data) return <p>No profile data</p>

    return (
      <div>
        <h1>{data.name}</h1>
        <p>{data.bio}</p>
      </div>
    )
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing client components with server components.

Check this link which will give more idea on this : https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/loading-ui-and-streaming#example

Below code will remove the error.

```
// page.tsx
const Home = ({ searchParams }) => {
  const searchKeyword =
  typeof searchParams.keyword === "string" ? searchParams.keyword : "";
  
    return (
    <main className='p-6 flex justify-center w-full min-h-screen bg-black'>
      <InfiniteScrollData
        search={searchKeyword}
      />
    </main>
  );
};
export default Home;
```

This component has to load the data. You can't implement infinite loading on server component. That has to be done in client only.

```
// InfiniteScrollData.tsx

"use client";

// imports


const InfiniteScrollImages: = ({
  search,
  initialData,
}) => {
  let initialData = await getPhotos({ query: searchKeyword });
  const [data, setData] = useState(initialData);
  const [page, setPage] = useState(1);
  const [loaderRef, inView] = useInView();

  const loadMoreData = useCallback(async () => {
    const next = page + 1;
    const response = await getData({ query: search, page: next });
    if (response?.results?.length) {
      setPage(next);
      setData((prev) => [...prev, ...(response?.results || [])]);
    }
  }, [page, search]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (inView) {
      loadMoreData();
    }
  }, [inView, loadMoreData]);

  return (
    <>
      <div>
        {photos?.map((item) => (
          <Card key={item.id} data={item} />
        ))}
      </div>
      <div ref={loaderRef}>
        <Loader />
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default InfiniteScrollImages;
```

Answer (score -2):

Your error directly says that you cannot do `await` functions in client components, so you should find away to get rid of that in your code:

```
const Home = ({ searchParams }) => { // no async
```